# Flutter: Determine when Dialog was successfully presented

Tags: flutter, dart

With the goal of presenting a loading `Dialog` while waiting for a `Stream` to emit a value, I built a simple utility function.

The function takes a *(broadcasted)* `stream`, and will display a loading `Dialog` until a first value is emitted. The subscription is then canceled and the dialog will close itself so I don't have to worry about it.

```
  static void wrapStreamWithLoadingModal(BuildContext context, {@required Stream stream}) {
    BuildContext dialogContext;
    StreamSubscription subscription;

    subscription = stream.listen((_) {
      subscription.cancel();
      if (dialogContext != null) {
        Navigator.pop(dialogContext);
      }
    }, onError: (error) {
      subscription.cancel();
      if (dialogContext != null) {
        Navigator.pop(dialogContext);
      }
    });

    showCupertinoDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext dContext) {
        dialogContext = dContext;
        return Center(
          child: Container(
            decoration:
                BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0), color: Colors.white),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            width: 120.0,
            height: 100.0,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                new Text('Loading...'),
                new CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

This works perfectly fine, except in one case: if the stream emits while the Dialog is *being* drawn, meaning that it did not appear on screen yet, then my reference to its `BuildContext` is null and I can't dismiss anything.

How can I know when the dialog is successfully presented? Or prevent this edge case? Also, maybe I should use some `key` instead of referencing the context, feel free to suggest.

Comment: actually you dont need `dialogContext` - if you call `Navigator.of(dialogContext)` or `Navigator.of(context)` they both return the same `NavigatorState` object

Comment: I was creating a different context in order to know if the dialog was presented or not, because then I wouldn't pop it if the dialog is null

Comment: ok, i made quick test and it seems that [Overlay](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html) is more handy with `OverlayState.insert` and `OverlayEntry.remove` methods

Comment: @pskink yes it works much better than dialog. Please post as an answer ?

Comment: great, feel free to post a self answer - maybe your solution will be better than mine?

Comment: Overlay is the best solution so far

Answer (score 0):

I'd go in this route,

```
showMyDialog();
//insert some delay here
await stream.first
pop();

showMyDialog(){
 showCupertinoDialog(//...
}
```

OR
use

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

if you are unable pop with existing Navigator

Comment: Tested and it works. Does this assume that it takes one tick for the Dialog to be drawn? There's no way that even with this, the stream will fire while `showCupertinoDialog` does its thing?

Comment: the dialog will never be inserted into the widget tree if there is already a stream event before inserting, what do you mean by tick? a stream event?

Comment: The issue is that the event is not necessarely here "before" I show the dialog, it actually emits between my call to `showDialog` and when the dialog is actually presented. If its the case, I have no way to dismiss it.

Also, stream.first is a Future and should be awaited, right? It will always be != null in your case because `first` is just returning the future itself...

Comment: you can do this right, show the dialogue>check whether stream.first exists>pop screen or continue awaiting for stream.first,  you could add some delay before checking the stream.first so there is time for the dialog to be inserted into the tree